# syntax error near "@domain" SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having an issue using SQLite. When i'm trying to raw my query here is the error I'm having.

```
03-05 11:40:54.916: E/AndroidRuntime(6136): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@domain": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM shopping_list WHERE shopping_list_owner = mail@domain.fr
```

Here is the function that raw the query :

```
    public List<ShoppingListModel> getAllShoppingListByOwner(String owner) {
    List<ShoppingListModel> shoppingList = new ArrayList<ShoppingListModel>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST + " WHERE " + SHOPPING_LIST_OWNER + " = " + owner;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ShoppingListModel list = new ShoppingListModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPPING_LIST_NAME)), 
                                                           cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPPING_LIST_ID)), 
                                                           cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPPING_LIST_DATE_CREATION)),
                                                           cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPPING_LIST_OWNER)));
            shoppingList.add(list);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return shoppingList;
}
```

`owner` is a `String` that contains something like this => "mail@domail.fr"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL string literals need to be in `''` single quotes.

However, it's better to use `?` placeholders and bind args for literals:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST + " WHERE " + SHOPPING_LIST_OWNER + " = ?";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { owner });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Like This

```
public List<ShoppingListModel> getAllShoppingListByOwner(String owner) {
    List<ShoppingListModel> shoppingList = new ArrayList<ShoppingListModel>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST + " WHERE " + SHOPPING_LIST_OWNER + " = " + "'"+owner+"'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ShoppingListModel list = new ShoppingListModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPPING_LIST_NAME)), 
                                                           cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPPING_LIST_ID)), 
                                                           cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPPING_LIST_DATE_CREATION)),
                                                           cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SHOPPING_LIST_OWNER)));
            shoppingList.add(list);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return shoppingList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *owner* should be surrounded by quotes.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST + " WHERE " + SHOPPING_LIST_OWNER + "=\'" + owner + '\'';
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your variable owner is of type String , You need to add opening and closing `'` single quotes. Use your query following way,

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST + 
" WHERE " + SHOPPING_LIST_OWNER + " ='" + owner + "'";
```