# SQLite Exception error 1

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having an SQLite error in my application, it seems simple but I can't figure out how to solve it or what it's causing it. I've tried to fix it but with no success of course that's why I'm here. Any help would be appreciated.

Java code:

```
public HashMap<String, String> getProfileDetails(String pid, String email){
        HashMap<String,String> profile = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_FAVOURITE_PROFILES + " WHERE " + KEY_PID + " = " 
        + pid + " AND " + KEY_USER_EMAIL + " = " + email;


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Moves to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            profile.put("pid", cursor.getString(1));
            profile.put("petname", cursor.getString(2));
            profile.put("pettype", cursor.getString(3));
            profile.put("email", cursor.getString(4));
            profile.put("username", cursor.getString(5));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // returns user
        return profile;
    }
```

**Log:**

```
   05-14 11:45:49.815: E/SQLiteLog(7161): (1) near "@hotmail": syntax error
05-14 11:45:49.829: E/AndroidRuntime(7161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 11:45:49.829: E/AndroidRuntime(7161): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@hotmail": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM profiles WHERE pid = 26 AND email = lucsantis@hotmail.com
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195612/syntax-error-near-domain-sqlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings must be surrounded by single quotes.
So, this:

```
+ pid + " AND " + KEY_USER_EMAIL + " = " + email;
```

must be:

```
+ pid + " AND " + KEY_USER_EMAIL + " = '" + email + "'";
```

Even better, you can **bind your parameters**:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_FAVOURITE_PROFILES + " WHERE " + KEY_PID + " =  ? AND " + KEY_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"" + pid, email});
```

Comment: Haha that was simple how stupid, I was trying my way around before I posted the question adding quotes but I didn't do it right, anyway now it's working fine, thanks!